# Mercurial, can't clone on Windows 7, "abort: No usable temporary filename found"

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, clone

I'm trying to clone a repo and it's failing on Windows 7.  Looks like this:

```
C:\nodropwork>hg clone repoalias examplerepo
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1244 changesets with 9087 changes to 4816 files (+2 heads)
updating to branch default
abort: No usable temporary filename found
C:\nodropwork>cd examplerepo
C:\nodropwork\examplerepo>hg up
abort: No usable temporary filename found
```

The filesystem then contains the first few directories of source (the first 3, out of about 10 total).

When I try this on WinXP, the clone works, although I get an error message on a particular file:

```
updating to branch default
[partial xml console output removed]
abort: The system cannot find the file specified:
C:\nodropwork\examplerepo\collateral/con.xml
```

When the guy who owns the repo does a test clone on his Ubuntu system, it works fine with no errors or warnings at all.

Googling on "No usable temporary filename found" I see Mercurial source with functions like rename() and unlink(), notably in windows.py. Not sure what to do with this info though.

I'm guessing that there is something in the repo that WinXP tolerate but Win 7 chokes on. We tried removing con.xml from the repo and this didn't fix. About to give up and use WinXP.

Has anyone seen this before? Know a fix? Clever idea for troubleshooting?

Comment: Also, can you execute this command: `hg manifest tip` and show the output?

Comment: Using version 1.8.1, the version integrating with Python 2.6 for Windows, the x86 version (it's an x64 machine, though).

I did start with a different version (the x64 version) and got the same error (that's where this all started).

Comment: `hg manifest tip` shows what looks like a complete source tree w/ 2151 files.

Comment: I mean't, show to us. Sounds like a filename problem.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure my client wants me to share his source tree. Maybe later. I did look at the manifest and didn't _notice_ any screamingly bad filenames. I have another thing to look into, but I'm out of time right now. I'll probably comment again tomorrow if you're still watching--I appreciate the feedback so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved, the problem was the "con.xml" file in the repo (apparently it was still hiding somewhere even though we thought we removed).

You can't name a file "con"-anything on Windows, "con" is a forbidden name.

We renamed the con.xml file and the repo clones and updates correctly on Win 7 now.