# mercurial: No usable temporary file name found

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a repo on a network drive (served by Windows server), with local repos pushing/pulling to it on the various machines I work on.

I just dealt with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677564/tortoisehg-push-or-commit-fail-with-ret-255), and solved it by cloning the repo from the network drive to a local disk, pushing, then cloning it back again. The machine from which I did this had not problem pushing further changes after this.

Now I just tried pushing from my laptop, and this happens:

```
% hg --debug push "Z:\[main repo]"
pushing to Z:\[main repo]
query 1; heads
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
listing keys for "bookmarks"
2 changesets found
list of changesets:
2ed25c8975482734e3b9eed828573fd711d26fd8
19a424c011ffd0c887cf1d54ed0b537a6c1af714
adding changesets
add changeset 2ed25c897548
add changeset 19a424c011ff
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding GEM.py revisions
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: No usable temporary file name found
[command returned code 255 Thu Mar 09 18:51:11 2017]
```

The only info pertaining to this error message I have found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543294/mercurial-cant-clone-on-windows-7-abort-no-usable-temporary-filename-found), and I definitely have no files named `con.*`in my project. There are several named `con*.py` but they have never been a problem, and both the laptop and my workstation are running Windows 7, and I've been working on this project for a few years now.

I have happily pushed from this laptop for over a year, and it was never a problem. I don't really have any good idea where to even start looking. Could it be connected to the fact that my workstation had the main repo opened at the same time? It was definitely not doing anything to it at the time.

**Update:**
I ran `hg verify`, and this is what it returns -- no problem as far as aI can tell

```
% hg --debug verify
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
73 files, 74 changesets, 226 total revisions
[command completed successfully Fri Mar 10 08:58:02 2017]
```

Comment: The problem likely is with the use of the repo on your network drive. While it is supposed to work, it doesn't always work flawlessly, e.g.  network drives sometimes disallow the VCS to gain the write lock it needs.

Comment: Might also be related to the samba config, e.g. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/52804/mercurial-central-repository-at-a-samba-location
Generally search for samba and mercurial and you'll get the impression that it's not necessarily the best of combinations - or at least not one which works without much thought and tweaking on the config side, possibly sambas side.

Comment: @planetmaker: Yes, it must have to do with the network drive and how mercurial deals with it. However, I haven't even tried committing from Linux, and on Windows I don't have a lot of options. It's supposed to just work, and actually it should because Samba supports the Windows ACLs, not the POSIX/Linux ones. Also, I'd like to work out why this should be a problem now, and has not been one before.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same error as well.
I just ran tortoise hg as as administrator and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer yet but I would try the following:

1. Update to the latest mercurial version (4.1) and try again
2. Verify the repo integrity with hg verify
3. Although I understand it always worked as is, try to rename all the con.py files. The thing with CON is that it represents a device, I think it comes from DOS times :-)
4. If I understand correctly, you push to Z:[main repo] where Z: is a Windows share. Try to push to the same repo in another way, with ssh (requires some setup, yes)

Good luck, very bizarre problem :-/

Comment: The "con" thing was a typesetting error in my post: the ``*`` placeholder was not shown by the system -- have updated the post. I do not have anything starting with ``con.``, and I would not be able to remove any of the ``con*.py`` because they're part of external libraries included in my project.

Comment: hg verify seems to find no problems -- I added the results to the question

Comment: Just updated to 4.1 (thanks for making me aware of the update!) -- but the outcome has not changed at  all :(

Comment: It's not possible to access the shared folder via ssh, as far as I can tell, neither ftp or anything like that. It's SAMBA only, and its configuration is not in my hands

Comment: @Zak Given also planetmaker comments, it really seems related to Samba. Yes, you wrote that it used to work, but since the Samba server is outside your control, it might have changed something :-) To troubleshoot, as an alternative to ssh, can you connect to that server somehow? If yes, you can try with "hg serve" while on the server. If you are not familiar with "serve", have a look at the documentation. If it works, then it is really Samba or how Samba is configured.